# python: if column condition met change value in that column

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I add 10 to any value in column col2 if it's value is 0. The general case for a larger data frame.

```
     col1 col2
row1    1   2
row2    3   0
```

So I get:

```
     col1 col2
row1    1   2
row2    3   10
```

This gets me the correct row:

```
df2.loc[lambda df2: df2['col2'] == 0 ]
```

This does the entire row, which I don't want:

```
df2.loc[df2['col2'] == 0 ] = 10
```

Comment: `df.replace(0, 10)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where()`

```
import numpy as np

df['col2'] = np.where(df['col2']==0, 10, df['col2'])
```